# Error while installing Balena Etcher

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, iso, 23.10

I was trying to create a bootable USB with BalenaEtcher but encountered an error when installing the program.

I downloaded the main `.deb` file from the [github release page](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases) but when I run `sudo apt install ./balena-etcher_1.19.5_amd64.deb`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'balena-etcher' instead of './balena-etcher_1.19.5_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 balena-etcher : Depends: gconf-service but it is not installable
                 Depends: gconf2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I guess this may be connected with me using `23.10`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT (as proposed by [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506762/error-while-installing-balena-etcher#comment2644339_1506762))**

`sudo apt install gconf-service`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gconf-service is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gconf-service' has no installation candidate
```

`sudo apt install gconf2`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gconf2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gconf2' has no installation candidate
```

`sudo apt install libgconf-2-4`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libgconf-2-4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgconf-2-4' has no installation candidate
```

`sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease             
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease           
Hit:7 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mjasnik/ppa/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`apt policy gconf-service`:

```
gconf-service:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151999/discussion-on-question-by-john-carter-error-while-installing-balena-etcher); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome has moved away from `gconf` to `dconf` long time ago. Last releases that did package `gconf` is Ubuntu Lunar 23.04 and Debian Bookworm 12. Then it was dropped from later releases.

These good sites to check status of any package:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/
- https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Found it is already reported upstream:  [Debian Testing has removed gconf2 packages. #4096](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/4096)

- Best option is to use appimage package or alternative tool, till fixed upstream.
- Another, option is to force installing `gconf` from old release repository. But this method is dirty and result is not predictable, it can even break Gnome.
- If this is special case that this tool is the only solution , you may setup older Ubuntu in VirtualBox and install Balena Etcher in it. (This probably will not work in very weak PC like chrome notebooks)

Comment: So basically I either have to wait until Balena changes their program to run on `dconf`?

Comment: @JohnCarter ,  AppImage and VM still an option. I updated my answer.